# In PHP, how can I migrate Selenium RC to WebDriver?

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I have written a Selenium test case using PHP - now I want to migrate it to WebDriver. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver-backed Selenium client is not implemented in PHP bindings. Thus you will have to rewrite your existing tests using WebDriver API.

Try Facebook PHP bindings for WebDriver - https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver